# What happens on a JMS queue when onMessage() throws a JMSException?

Tags: spring, exception, jms

I'm using Spring 2.5 with my custom class that implements MessageListener.  If a JmsException is thrown in my onMessage( ) method, what happens to the state of the queue?

Is the message considered "delivered" by the queue the moment onMessage is called?  Or does the JmsException trigger some kind of rollback and the message is re-entered on the queue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18):

From the JMS 1.1 spec...

4.5.2 Asynchronous Delivery

A client can register an object that implements the JMS MessageListener interface with a MessageConsumer. As messages arrive for the consumer, the provider delivers them by calling the listener’s onMessage method.

It is possible for a listener to throw a RuntimeException; however, this is considered a client programming error. Well-behaved listeners should catch such exceptions and attempt to divert messages causing them to some form of application-specific ‘unprocessable message’ destination.

The result of a listener throwing a RuntimeException depends on the session’s acknowledgment mode.

- AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE or
  DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE - the message
  will be immediately redelivered. The
  number of times a JMS provider will
  redeliver the same message before
  giving up is provider-dependent. The
  JMSRedelivered message header field
  will be set for a message redelivered
  under these circumstances.
- CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE - the next message
  for the listener is delivered. If a
  client wishes to have the previous
  unacknowledged message redelivered,
  it must manually recover the session.
- Transacted Session - the next message
  for the listener is delivered. The
  client can either commit or roll back
  the session (in other words, a
  RuntimeException does not
  automatically rollback the session).

JMS providers should flag clients with message listeners that are throwing
RuntimeExceptions as possibly malfunctioning.

Comment: what will happen if an unhandled exception occurs inside the onMessage and the method never returns ? Is there a possibility that the message is not removed from the queue ? does that mean (for a synchronous client) the onMessage must return for an acknowledgement so that the message can be removed from queue ?

Comment: @bluelurker - I'm confused by your question.  The spec language is about allowing a RuntimeException to propagate out from the onMessage() method. If your method completes by throwing an exception, that's an alternative to a "normal" return. So I don't understand the "never returns" part. Instead of returning, it completed by having an exception propagate out.

Comment: @JohnM From onMessage() method if I throw RunTimeException then that message will remain in queue and be delivered again. Again message will be thrown. It will be delivered again. And so on .... is my understanding correct ? This is what I see happening in my testing.

Comment: @KaushikLele On endless redelivery... I think it's a non-standardized thing, some vendor products have a feature to limit endless redelivery. Sometimes called a "poison message queue" where the message goes after N failed delivery attempts. Check your vendor's docs.